# Using Express Checkout Paypal on Ruby On Rails , Return Blank Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal

i am encountered some problem in my apps .
i am following tutorial from https://launchschool.com/blog/basic-paypal-checkout-processing-in-rails to Process Payments With Paypal but when my apps redirect to the sandbox paypal it just show a blank page.

Here is my code

## Orders Controller

```
def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    @order.add_line_items_from_cart(@cart)
    respond_to do |format|
    if @order.save
      redirect_to @order.paypal_url(orders_path(@order))
    else
      render :new 
    end
  end
```

## Order Model

```
protect_from_forgery except: [:hook]
  def hook
    params.permit! # Permit all Paypal input params
    status = params[:payment_status]
    if status == "Completed"
      @order = Order.find params[:invoice]
      @order.update_attributes notification_params: params, status: status, transaction_id: params[:txn_id], purchased_at: Time.now
    end
    render nothing: true
  end
```

## secret.yml

```
development:
  secret_key_base: 0351c7e4eb70df5503d739c085d7a75dae662a55e95cf257b4a2e3edaa6985623372b7d20fc3ea59fe58d9ec94243e36a7250007ad2d9734b68cf29f90cca682
  paypal_host: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com
  app_host: http://0.0.0.0:3000
```

## Routes.rb

```
post "/hook" => "orders#hook"
post "/orders/:id" => "orders#show"
```

Sorry for the my bad english ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

respond_to requires you to specify which formats the action will respond to, like

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to .... }
end
```

or

```
format.any(:html, :js) { ... }
```

In your case it doesn't seem like you need to use respond_to

Comment: i already erase the `respond_to do |format|` , but still when the apps redirect to sandbox paypal it give me blank page.

Comment: @MuhammadRahmatullah what's the output on the server and on the javascript console?

Comment: the console output was :
`Redirected to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?amount=1485&business=merchant%40rahmat.com&cmd=_xclick&invoice=44&item_name=Rahmat+Books&item_number=10&notify_url=http%3A%2F%2F0.0.0.0%3A3000%2Fhook&quantity=1&return=http%3A%2F%2F0.0.0.0%3A3000%2Forders.44&upload=1`
Completed 302 Found in 58ms (ActiveRecord: 26.8ms)